# Control the range of values in the map legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I would like to increase the range of values in the graph. In the example, the values range from 50 to 200. However, I need to distribute the values as follows: 50 75 100 125 150 175 200 and preferably using the `scale_fill_gradientn` function, is it possible?

```
volcano %>% reshape2::melt(varnames=c("x", "y")) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x,y, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + 
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hcl.colors(15, palette = "Purple-Green"), limits=c(50,200))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `breaks` along with `labels` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)
volcano %>% 
   reshape2::melt(varnames=c("x", "y")) %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y, fill=value)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hcl.colors(15, palette = "Purple-Green"),
         limits=c(50,200),
       breaks = c(50,75,100,125, 150, 175, 200), 
           labels=c(50,75,100,125, 150, 175, 200))
```

[image]